# flutter dropdown from jsonapi

Tags: flutter, dart

This code is working perfectly fine and showing data in listview:

```
return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            print(snapshot.data.data[index]);
                            return ListTile(
                              title:
                                Text(snapshot.data.data[index].id.toString()),
                              subtitle: Text(
                                snapshot.data.data[index].attributes.name==null?'Not Set':snapshot.data.data[index].attributes.name,
                              ),
                             
                            );
                          });
```

but when I am using the same in dropdown widget, it is throwing error:

```
return DropdownButton<String>(
                     hint: Text("Select"),
                     value: _selectedTestkit,
                     onChanged: (newValue) {
                     setState(() {
                     _selectedTestkit = newValue;
                                              });
                                            },
    items: snapshot.data.data.map((item) =>
    DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              child: Text(item.id),
                value:item.id,
        )).toList(),
                                          );
                                        }
                                    }
                                  }),
                            ),
```

This the error I am getting:

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: . 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 855 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

but in listview builder I am getting this result:

```
1 testname1
2 testname2
3 testname3
4 testname4
```

**Update:**

I used to add a custom value in dropdown list like this:

```
List data = json.decode(response.body);
data.add('other');
```

and the other will show up in the dropdownlist.

but when I am trying in the present future method

```
Future<TestkitList> fetchTestkitId() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();    
    Uri testkiturl = Uri.https(staging_url, "testkits");
    
    final response = await http.get(testkiturl, headers: {
      'Accept-Type': 'application/json',
      "Content-Type": "application/json",      

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
      // then parse the JSON.
      print(response.body);
      print('this was printed before json decode');
      var responsetestkit = Future.value(testkitListFromMap(response.body));

      responsetestkit.add('other');//here I am trying to add a custom item for dropdown
      setState(() {
        _testkit = responsetestkit;
        print(_testkit);
      });
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      print(response.body);
      throw Exception('Failed to load TESTKITLIST');
    }
  }
```

but here I am getting the error - `The method 'add' isn't defined for the type 'Future'.`

Comment: What is the question / problem ?

Comment: with the new json response I am not able to build the dropdown.

Comment: @Joshi, could you post your model and full JSON string to allow me reproduce this case. Thanks.

Comment: @chunhunghan - Thank you so much, that part I am able to resolve. but I have another issue I have updating the code.

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {      
      return Future.value(testkitListFromMap(response.body));
    } else {     
      throw Exception('Failed to load TESTKITLIST');
    }
```

to this:

```
 if (response.statusCode == 200) {      
      return Future.value(testkitListFromMap(response.body["data"]));//you need to add "data" to access your items based on your data class.
    } else {     
      throw Exception('Failed to load TESTKITLIST');
    }
```

Comment: If I add `jsonDecode` - I get the error - `Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String')`

Comment: @Joshi I edited my answer, change your `response.body` into `response.body["data"]`.

Comment: No in the fetch function I am not getting any error. only I am not able to build the dropdown widget with the returned data.

Comment: then it gives error - The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'

Comment: How do you know for sure that the API is fetching the data correctly and you insist on it?